# Stop UIView animation or detect if view is animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

There's an array with uiviews. Their frames are set due to current `interfaceOrientation`

Then we add these views to `self.view` programmatically using

```
-(void)placeView
{
    if ([self.arrayWithViews count] > 0)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f animations:^{
            UIView *currentView = [self.arrayWithViews lastObject];
            [currentView setAlpha:0.f];
            [self.view addSubview:currentView];
            [currentView setAlpha:1.f];
            [self.arrayWithViews removeLastObject];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [self placeView];
        }];
    }
}
```

Now, if the orientation change happens the views keep adding (with coordinates corresponding to previous orientation).

The question is - how to stop the animation process or how to prevent interface orientation change while the animation takes place.

**P.S.** `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations]` doesn't work (I didn't figure out why)

Could you please advise what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeAllAnimations` will still call `completion` block, so you repeat to call `placeView`, so you need add a flag:

```
-(void)placeView
    {
        if(!self.runAni){ //Add a flag to stop repeat to call [self placeView]
            return;
        }
        if ([self.arrayWithViews count] > 0)
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.f animations:^{
                UIView *currentView = [self.arrayWithViews lastObject];
                [currentView setAlpha:0.f];
                [self.view addSubview:currentView];
                [currentView setAlpha:1.f];
                [self.arrayWithViews removeLastObject];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [self placeView];
            }];
        }
    }
```

to stop animation, you should do :

```
self.runAni = NO;
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

begin to do:

```
self.runAni = YES;
[self placeView];
```

Comment: Thank you!
I've got the main idea about completion block, now I'll dig further.